# Bootstrap nav inside a React app

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, electron

I'm trying to implement a Bootstrap nav inside a React + Electron app.

This is the JSX code I've written:

```
render: function () {
  if (this.state.loading) {
    return (
      <div className="jumbotron">
        <h1 className="display-3">Let us load your data</h1>
        <p>It may take a while</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ul className="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li role="presentation" className="active">
          <a href="#">
            Home
          </a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
          <a href="#">
            Profile
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And this is what is rendered:

[image: Bootstrap nav]

It's seems like the `nav-pills`, `nav-stacked` and `active` classes are not rendered.

I've also tried to render a table:

```
return (
  <div>
    <table className="table table-striped table-bordered">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
);
```

And this one works as expected:

[image: Bootstrap table]

Is there any reason that the nav doesn't work?

Comment: can you post the whole render() method please ?

Comment: I've done it by now.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code, can you check with the DOM inspector if the DOM is rendered properly ?

Comment: It's rendered like I want it to `<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked"><li role="presentation" class="active">` and `<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">`. I can see bootstrap.css inside my sources or network dev tools tab containing rules about `.nav-pills` and `.nav-stacked`...

Comment: I just created a JSFiddle, and everything works fine http://jsfiddle.net/KeitIG/nyL90bq8/1/, maybe you can compare with your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project was using Bootstrap 4 and not Bootstrap 3 as I thought...

Answer (score 0):

try to use react-bootstrap.link - https://react-bootstrap.github.io/

Comment: Why would I need that? I'm just using Bootstrap as a CSS library.